# Building Linux C++ project imported to Visual Studio 2015 by VisualGDB

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2012, import, visualgdb

I have a small Linux project which has a OpenCV as its dependency.

In Linux (Ubuntu: running in VMware), I’ve already compiled and built it by using bash script without any error.

In order to develop it more efficiently, I’m  going to import it into Visual Studio 2015 from Ubuntu by using VisualGDB.

According to https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/linux/import/, I’ve imported it into VS2015 successfully, but whenever I built it, I have got a following error:

> “Error MSB3073      The command “”C:\Program Files (x86)\Sysprogs\VisualGDB\VisualGDB.exe” /build “D:\tmp\LinuxProject3\LinuxProject3\LinuxProject3.vcxproj” “/solution:D:\tmp\LinuxProject3\LinuxProject3.sln” “/config:Debug” “/platform:VisualGDB”” exited with code 1.”

In order to check out whether my project had a problem or not, I imported the source of Midnight Commander just illustrated in above link with all default setting without any changes,  but unfortunately the result was same.

By the way, there is no error in creating(not importing) new Linux C++ project, connecting with VMware, compiling, building and  debugging in VS2015.

What’s wrong? What mistakes did I make?

Comment: Try pasting the command in the error message into a command prompt and running it you __may__ get additional messages (check the nesting of ").

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.